# Need to click twice to add/remove a Class with Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I read some of the answers here similar to my question, but I still don't understand what's going on.

I have this JS snippet:

```
function renderButtons() {
  let buttonCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  let arrayOfBtn = [...buttonCollection];

  arrayOfBtn.forEach(function(element) {
    function modifyClass() {
      element.classList.toggle("active");
    } 
   element.addEventListener("click", modifyClass);
  })
}
```

That is meant to add/remove the `class` "active" of a `button` when I click on it.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="panel controls">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button class="btn btn-pepperonni active">Pepperonni</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="btn btn-mushrooms active">Mushrooms</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="btn btn-green-peppers active">Green peppers</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="btn btn-sauce active">White sauce</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="btn btn-crust active">Gluten-free crust</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

And it works, the problem is that I have to click twice each time on the `button` to add or remove the `class` of that button in particular.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I can’t replicate your issue. May you convert your code to a runnable snippet?

Comment: Sorry, here it is the runnable snippet: https://codepen.io/pablinx/pen/OJPaVzL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Remove your RenderButtons function and instead toggle the "active" class once you click the button like this on every ingredient:

```
document.querySelector('.btn.btn-pepperonni').onclick = function() {
  state.pepperonni = !state.pepperonni;
  renderEverything()
  this.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

Basically what you do is you call two onclick events on the button and they do not work together.
Also you are over complicating the whole thing with your RenderButtons Functions :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, here it is the runnable snippet: https://codepen.io/pablinx/pen/OJPaVzL

Comment: Ok I found the problem in your code. Hope this simple solution helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS must be loaded at the end of your HTML. Your HTML will load the content from TOP to BOTTOM. So your Scirpt want to access "btn" elements, which are at the moment not genereted.

First HTML, then JS.

For such a short function, you could use a inline function as below.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="panel controls">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <button class="btn btn-pepperonni active">Pepperonni</button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button class="btn btn-mushrooms active">Mushrooms</button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button class="btn btn-green-peppers active">Green peppers</button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button class="btn btn-sauce active">White sauce</button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button class="btn btn-crust active">Gluten-free crust</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
    </body>
    <script>

      var buttonCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

      for (var i = 0; i < buttonCollection.length; i++) 
      {
        buttonCollection[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
          this.classList.toggle("active");
       });
      }


    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: No, sorry, the HTML is properly written, but I just shared here the snippets that mattered for the question. The full code is here: https://codepen.io/pablinx/pen/OJPaVzL

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers have shown how to fix your original code I have tried to find a simplified version of what you want to do.

In my solution I am using a "delegated event binding": the click event is bound to the parent `<div>` element and fires only when the actual click target is of class `btn`. This approach will work on elements that have not even been created at the time of the binding. And it is more "lightweight", as there is only one binding.

```js
document.querySelector("div.panel.controls")
 .addEventListener("click",function(ev){
   var cl=ev.target.classList;
   if (cl.contains("btn")) cl.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.active {background-color: #fcc}
```

```html
<div class="panel controls">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button class="btn btn-pepperonni active">Pepperonni</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="btn btn-mushrooms active">Mushrooms</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="btn btn-green-peppers active">Green peppers</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="btn btn-sauce active">White sauce</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="btn btn-crust active">Gluten-free crust</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```